# Geolocation in my app

Tags: android, geolocation

How to store different `location` in `database` and retrieve the `location` on `Google maps` in `Android studio` . I want to add `location` with product details because user can easily found the product `Location`

Comment: Have you done some research?

Comment: yes i did but i want to show the location of product in my app

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store data and retrieve them, 
Refer this document for get google map work in your android app (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start)
then add your locations on the map using some code like below

```
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    LatLng point = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(point);                                                
    markerOptions.title("Title"); // This title will be shown when you click on a marker                                                
  markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon));
   mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```